# Perceptron algorithm is not working as I desired

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, data-analysis, perceptron

I recently tried implementing perceptron algorithm but I was not getting the desired output.
Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

with open("D:/data.txt",'r') as data:  #importing the data
    column = data.read()
split = np.array(column.split('\n'))

final =[]
for string in split:
    final.append(string.split(','))
df = pd.DataFrame(final,columns=['x','y','response'])
df['x'] = df['x'].astype(float)
df['y'] = df['y'].astype(float)
df['response'] = df['response'].astype(int)

X = np.array(df[['x','y']])
y = np.array(df['response'])

def perceptron_algorithm(x,y,learning_rate=0.01,num_epoch=25):
    np.random.seed(2)
    
    x_min, x_max = min(x.T[0]), max(x.T[0])
    y_min, y_max = min(x.T[1]), max(x.T[0])
    
    w = np.array(np.random.rand(2,1))
    b = np.random.rand(1)[0] + x_max
    
    print(w,b)
    
    for i in range(num_epoch):
        w,b = perceptronstep(x,y,w,b,learning_rate)
        print(w,b)
    return w,b

def perceptronstep(x,y,w,b,learning_rate):
    
    for i in range(len(x)):
        y_hat = prediction(x[i],w,b)
        
        if y_hat-y[i] == 1:
            for j in range(len(w)):
                w[j] += x[i][j]*learning_rate
            b += learning_rate
        elif y_hat-y[i] == -1:
            for j in range(len(w)):
                w[j] -= x[i][j]*learning_rate
            b -= learning_rate
    return w,b

def prediction(x,w,b):
    return step(np.matmul(x,w)+b)

def step(t):
    if t >=0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

w,b = perceptron_algorithm(X,y)
```

This is the resulting line:

[image: scatter plot with the predicted line]

This is how the data looks:

[image: data]

Is there something wrong with my code ?

Here is the link to the data file:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1TSug9tE6bljyBFv-u3mIGWW6F_3ZY2oa?usp=sharing

Edit: I have added the initial part of the code so it will be clear what I am trying to do.
Edit 2: I have added the data file and the "import pandas as pd" line of code

Comment: what is np ? `import numpy as np ?` can you add the missing import and xy_minmax x,y ?

Comment: @Soleil-MathieuPrévot I have added the entire code.

Comment: Good. Can you also post the data file ? (a link suffice if it is big). Is pd for pandas ? `import pandas as pd` ?

Comment: @Soleil-MathieuPrévot I have included the link for the data. ( the data is just 100 rows). I am learning this algorithm so the data is just made up.
Also pd is for pandas. I have included that with the latest edit.

Comment: @Khalid Saifullah you are wrong, Perceptron and Linear regression are two different classifiers. Answering the original question, there is actually nothing wrong with your result (at least according to this picture), since Perceptron has no guarantees if your data are not linearly separable, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron#Convergence Convergence section.

Comment: @AnvarKurmukov Sure, I understand the concept. But the problem with my results are that as I increase the epochs the line only moves farther away from the points, as if it is not performing the perceptronstep function in my code above.

Comment: Once again, Perceptron algorithm does not give you any convergence guarantees unless your data is linearly separable, run your algorithm on a linearly separable case and it will work perfectly fine. For example, try this data 
`from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs`
`X,y = make_blobs(centers=2, random_state=10)`

Comment: From the first paragraph of a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron#Convergence

`... if the positive examples cannot be separated from the negative examples by a hyperplane. In this case, no "approximate" solution will be gradually approached under the standard learning algorithm, but instead, learning will fail completely.`

Comment: @AnvarKurmukov If the data is not linearly separable, a SVM with soft margins should be used. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61189/difference-between-a-svm-and-a-perceptron; see also 
*Support Vector Machine Soft Margin Classifiers: Error Analysis* Chen, 2004